# ¿Cómo cambiar el ícono de un programa .jar en NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, icono

Recientemente he creado una interfaz gráfica en **NetBeans** con ayuda de unos **JFrame**. Pero quiero cambiar el icono que te pone por default al ejecutar el programa:

[image: De este icono hablo]

Busqué un código en internet donde supuestamente te cambia el ícono; las configuraciones que hice son las siguientes:

1. Clic en el JFrame
2. Propiedades
3. iconimages > clic en los tres puntitos
4. En el menú despegable seleccioné **"Valor de componente existente"**
5. Activé la opción **Propiedades** > clic en los tres puntitos
6. En **Componente** seleccioné **"Form"**
7. Y en propiedades **iconimage**

En cuanto a la programación solo importé las siguientes librerías:

```
  import java.awt.Image;

  import java.awt.Toolkit;
```

Y el código siguiente para la ruta de imagen y establecerla:

```
   public Image getIconImage() {
    Image retValue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("IMG/logohp.png"));
    return retValue;
}
```

Anexo los paquetes de mi proyecto para que verifiquen que la ruta que indique sí es correcta: **"IMG/logohp.png"**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ejecuto mi programa me sigue apareciendo el ícono de la taza de Java y no sé por qué no se cambia si ya hice las configuraciones.

Así se pone cuando ejecuto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Configuraciones de las propiedades**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues yo lo veo bien es extraño que no te funcione, ¿puedes adjuntar una captura de tus propiedades? para ver como quedó

Comment: @Israel-ICM si claro

Comment: @Israel-ICM ya agregue la imagen

Comment: qué valor tiene la propiedad iconImages? Yo hubiera seleccionado en el dialogo llamada a método y en él hubiera puesto `getIconImage`. Por cierto, viendo el icnono del proyecto estás usando ant para construirlo, tal vez te sea relevante. Saludos.

Comment: Es posible que debas limpiar y reconstruir tu proyecto en `NetBeans` después de realizar este cambio para asegurarte de que se aplique correctamente. Puedes hacer esto yendo al menú `Build` y seleccionando `Clean and Build Project`. Luego, intenta ejecutar tu programa y deberías ver el nuevo icono en la barra de título de la ventana del `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

De las dos maneras deberia funcionar, sino puedes añadir al código después del `initComponents();`

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("IMG/logohp.png")).getImage());
```

Saludos.